# Many rows as a result of SELECT SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

The table consists of the **Record** and **Record author** fields. There is an employee table with the **Employee** and **His manager** fields. It is necessary to read records from the first table that belong to a specific manager or his employees. I tried like this:

```
SELECT* FROM fgac_table WHERE
    note_owner = 'manager_1' 
    OR note_owner = (SELECT empoyer_name FROM employers_table WHERE his_manager_name = 'manager_1');
```

Issued: `ORA-01427: single row subquery returns more than one row`. How should I fix the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple "solution" is to change `=` to `IN`:

```
or note_owner in (select empoyer_name ...)
```

Or, simply join those table:

```
select f.*
from fgac_table f join employers_table e on e.his_manager_name = f.note_owner
where f.note_owner = 'manager_1'
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that:
`SELECT empoyer_name FROM employers_table WHERE his_manager_name = 'manager_1'`

- that's the subselect in your example

returns more than one row. I can't determine whether that is what you expect or not.

If it's ok to get more than one row, rewrite the query to have an `IN()` predicate:

```
SELECT * FROM fgac_table 
WHERE note_owner = 'manager_1' 
    OR note_owner IN (
      SELECT empoyer_name 
      FROM employers_table 
      WHERE his_manager_name = 'manager_1'
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Whats is the result of query:

```
SELECT empoyer_name FROM employers_table WHERE his_manager_name = 'manager_1'
```

Then if you have a list of names may be you can replace condition the equal(=) to IN
like these:

```
SELECT* FROM fgac_table WHERE
note_owner = 'manager_1' 
OR note_owner IN (SELECT empoyer_name FROM employers_table WHERE his_manager_name = 'manager_1');
```

to help of another way please append screenshots of relational tables to have a better idea.

Psd, English is not my native language.

Regards.